# Cannot debug 'failed to connect to Database' exception in Java

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, exception

I am having a real problem in debugging one java exception.
The application is very old, written in an unknown(not any familiar framework) customized framework and i do not have access to the source code of the framework library, only the classes i have. I have access to application source coding and there i get an error 'failed to connect to database' sometimes(not frequent). I have identified the code block and the method there actually connects to the database and then runs an update query.
I thought it would be some SQL exception, so tried to caught it.. but it is not an SQL exception as the exception is caught by Exception catch block only. I do not get any clear idea from the stack trace of the exception. Below is the sample code. Can you please help me on how to identify the issue.

```
public void method_insert() throws Exception{
    boolean connected = false;
    ** 
    **
    db.setAutoCommit(false);
    **
    try {
        connected = db.connect("jdbc/dbconnect");

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error has occured in Connecting the database");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        try{
            String unqKey = "SELECT "+Constantes.ORA_SEQUENCES.get(..)+".NEXTVAL FROM DUAL";
            ResultSet rs = db.query(unqKey);

            if(rs.next()){
                curr_uk = rs.getInt(1);
                this.var1 = curr_uk;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("-------- An error occured in generating key from sequence ------");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String query = ** actual insert query**

        item_Insert = db.prepareStatement(query);
        try{    

            db.setAutoCommit(false);
            try{    

                **
                **

                db.update(item_Insert);
                db.commit();
                System.out.println("table has been successfully updated....");

            }catch (SQLException e) {
                db.rollback();
                System.out.println("table updation failed. Rolling back");
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            item_Insert.close();
        }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("SQL Errored occoured in transaction.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {          // Here the Exception is getting caught. Below i have provided some log info also.
        System.out.println("Errored occoured in transaction.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if(item_Insert != null)
                item_Insert.close();
        }catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("Some error has occured while closing item_Insert statement for method.");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            db.disconnect();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Some error has occured while disconnecting db connection for method.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> StackTrace in Log:

```
Errored occoured in transaction.
.....: java.lang.Exception: Failed to connect to database /
    at ...method(file.java:1009)
    ....
    ....
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at ...doFilter(SessionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:307)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:385)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:748)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:678)
    at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:871)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Please Note: I am using java 1.5 and tomcat 5.5 server for the application

Comment: jdbc/dbconnect is actually a bean defined in tomcat server config check if it is holding the right values.

Comment: Which is line 1009? I suppose the code you provided is inside `file.java`. Btw: you might want to run some decompiler....

Comment: line 1009 indicates the exact method in the java file where from the exception is thrown. and File.java is an exemplary name i used.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I have tried to find where it is actually bind in tomcat config in server.xml.. but i couldn't find it yet. though using the same connectivity, even the mentioned method works almost 95% times. So, i believe the connection string got right values.

Comment: Couple of things I  noticed. You are not closing the resultset. That may be causing some  problems.   Also are you  setting   autocommit back to true after setting it to false? Can you  indicate above where the exception occurs

Comment: Hi @danb, I haven't used resultset here, as the main query is an update statement and I have closed the PreparedStatement. Also, i have commented on the question where the exception is getting caught(19th line from bottom, requesting you to have a look). Thanks for looking into the issue

Comment: Sure you have used ResultSet. See `ResultSet rs = db.query(unqKey);`

Comment: Hi @danb , sorry for the confusion and yes i have used resultset to get value from the sequence. But the exception is not happening there. The exception is getting caught for the next update query where i have closed the update query with try block and caught exception in exception catch block.I will surely close the Resultset as you suggested, but i think the issue is with the later update query only.

Comment: @Ani It's very hard to tell from your code? Where is the variable db coming from? Is it static and if so is this method possibly being called by multiple threads.  Also noticed that even if the connection is not obtained you don't exit out of the method.

Comment: @danb db is not static. It is a method variable. I have just omitted that exact code. I can understand it is a bit difficult or odd for you to understand the whole coding here. But, request your valuable suggestion on this issue. Please let me know what other information you require. Thank you

Comment: @Ani Generally java.sql.Connection is used to issue queries and there is often a connection pool in a multi-threaded environment. Here "db" looks like a Connection, but seems to  have other methods.  If connection pools are being used the problem might be that the connections are not being closed.  Another possibility  is that "db" uses a Connection but it  is not multithread safe.  Is `method_insert` being called by multiple threads? This can happen if you are using a web server like tomcat.

Comment: @danb yes method_insert can be called by different sessions, hence i believe can be called by multiple threads. but how can i be sure about that? In the coding, no special care taken for multi-threading(you can see it also from the sample code i have posted). Another thing is..yes db is a sql connection,but it is wrapped in a custom class for this particular application. Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you give me some more help on how can i take some necessary precautions to avoid this runtime issue? sorry for being naive.. and thanks again

Comment: @Ani  Assuming "db"  wraps  connection, then `method_insert` is  not thread safe, since connections  are not thread safe.   So you would need to restructure all  the code.  Also are you using a connection pool?

Comment: @danb I am not even sure about that. i dont know how to check. What i see in application that it uses one JNDI type connection, like you see when creating a connection it is using "connected = db.connect("jdbc/dbconnect");" but i dont know where it is defined in tomcat config. But from code i couldn't be sure about connection pooling.I have in my hand connection.properties file, but i have no idea how "jdbc/dbconnect" actually finds that .properties file.

Comment: @Ani Sorry cannot help further without more access to the code  and more time.